# ASP.NET Web App, WCF Services and Database hosting

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf, security, hosting

I have a general question about database hosting in relation to WCF and ASP.NET. We are currently developing a new online web application in ASP.NET, which gets/posts data to our MSSQL database with a WCF service (three tier infrastructure).

Now later in development we will be launching our website and hosting it on an external provider. We are unsure whether to keep the database for the website internally on our own servers, or host it externally along with our provider (they offer database hosting options as well).

If we hosted it externally, we would obviously back it up internally using batch scripts etc.

One major concern is the security of the database, as we are only a small business with not much experience in web security architecture. Due to this, we are leaning towards an external provider for both the website and database, who would obviously have experience and the equipment to manage such things.

Could you please offer some opinions on the matter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always a risk associated with handing sensitive data off to an outside party, and trusting them to be as secure as you need.

There's no mystery here, someone at the provider will have enough access to look at your data if they really wanted to. So it all boils down to **how sensitive is your data?** Is there bank account info or social security numbers? For these reasons, our company cannot hand off such data to an outside party.

I'm a little confused though about one thing: if you could potentially host the database server when you go to production, why couldn't you host the website as well? Is it a matter of being able to handle high traffic?

**Update in response to your comment:**

It sounds like your data is somewhat sensitive, not highly sensitive. In which case if we're not being totally bonkers pedantic here, then you can reasonably assume a reputable hosting company will take the proper measures to secure your data, and from the sounds of it, they're probably more capable in this respect then your own company (not because you're careless or wet behind the ears, just because they would have considerable experience in this area where your company does not).

Now for the performance and hardware setup part if your comment... if you dont have the hardware or network infrastructure to meet your requirements, then you either a) upgrade your own infrastructure and hire the appropriate personnel to set it up and maintain it or b) you pay someone else to do it. Sounds like a no-brainer for you guys to go with option b.

Comment: Sorry that I'm only replying now. Hosting on our own servers is almost out of the question, as we have a poor site connection and we expect traffic to be fairly constant (we are using this site both internally and externally). There isn't so much sensitive information as in financial details or social security/NI details, just mainly emails, address data, remote connections to client computers etc.

We've opted for hosting off-site for now as we simply don't have the infrastructure to host locally.

Thanks for the response though :)